# Microsoft T-SQL XML Parsing Issue

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have XML similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML = 
'<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubElement xmlns="http://foobar">
    <foo1>bar1</foo1>
  </SubElement>
</RootElement>'
```

And I'm trying to parse it with the following SQL:

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://foobar')
SELECT 
    f.x.value('foo1[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from 
    @xml.nodes('/RootElement/SubElement') as f(x)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is the XML namespace on the SubElement node causing the issue? I ask because the following configuration works:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML = 
'<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubElement>
    <foo1>bar1</foo1>
  </SubElement>
</RootElement>'

SELECT 
    f.x.value('foo1[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from 
    @xml.nodes('/RootElement/SubElement') as f(x)
```

FYI:

```
select @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: By using the **default** XML namespace, you're applying that namespace to all nodes - but your **root node** `<RootElement>` is **not** in that namespace! You need to give your XML namespace an extension and then apply that XML namespace **only** to the `<SubElement>` tag (seem ljh's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://foobar' as Y)
SELECT 
    f.x.value('.', 'varchar(10)')
from 
    @xml.nodes('/RootElement/Y:SubElement') as f(x)
```